# French utterance in English Alexa Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, multilingual

Is it possible to make Alexa listen for a French word from an English Alexa skill?

When we make Alexa speak we can choose the language for example:

```
<speak>
    Welcome to Paris. <voice name="Celine"><lang xml:lang="fr-FR">Bienvenue à Paris</lang></voice>
</speak>
```

I want the user to be able to repeat "Bienvenue à Paris" and Alexa to understand this utterance.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa can support multiple languages. I would follow these instructions to add French to your skill so she can understand the sentence "Bienvenue à Paris"

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#add-a-language-to-an-existing-skill

Hope it helps
Ester

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to provide my Skill to another language but I want to be able to make my English skill understand/listen French words. I'm looking for a way to give a lang setting to intent samples.

Comment: Yes but to be able to do that you need to make your English skill not just an English skill but a multi language skill so it understands French language....i don't see any better way

Answer (score 1):

Learn French by smartio life is doing that, I have no clue how.

A user learning basic french does not want to have to configure his Alexa in French.
I've been thinking about creating utterances in english that would sound like the expected french (that would soon be very difficult to do), or use a phonetic utterance (I don't think it exists)